# What does the standard say about this pointer-to-member-function type template parameter? Is my code wrong, or is MSVS 16.6 buggy?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

Here's some code that works in GCC, Clang and MSVS (at least, those versions currently available on Compiler Explorer):

```
template <typename T, auto T::* MemberPtr>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const T& e) : _e(e) {}

    void operator()() const
    {
        (_e.*MemberPtr)();
    }

private:
    const T& _e;
};

struct Bar
{
    void baz() const {}

    auto bind()
    {
        using BindingType = Foo<Bar, &Bar::baz>;
        return BindingType(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar i;
    i.bind();
}
```

Starting from v16.6.1, however, MSVS rejects it:

```
Severity  Code   Description                                                                      Line
Error     C2973  'Foo': invalid template argument 'int'                                           23
Error     E2886  cannot deduce 'auto' template parameter type "auto T::*" from "void (Bar::*)()"  21
Error     C2440  'specialization': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'auto Bar::* '    22
Error     C3535  cannot deduce type for 'auto Bar::* ' from 'int'                                 23
Error     C2440  'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int Bar::* '                     23
```

The code can be "fixed" in that version by taking out the `T::*` qualifier for `MemberPtr`; so:

```
template <typename T, auto MemberPtr>
```

What does the standard say about this? Is VS v16.6.1 introducing a new regression, or is it now diagnosing code that was always subtly broken?

Comment: I was wondering whether the fact that the original `MemberPtr` declaration looks like a pointer-to-data-member type could be a problem, but the fact that only VS 16.6 rejects the code is supicious.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ack, good point, simplified too far ;) I'm sliding the `const` back in as it doesn't affect the results I'm talking about

Comment: BTW, for "last" compiler versions, it is gcc which fails [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3tEHLH)

Comment: @Jarod42 That's interesting. BTW you didn't need to add a call to the bound function

Comment: It is to enforce `Foo::operator()` instantiation (as the previously missing `const`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter/argument combo is valid as is

> **[temp.param]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#param-4) A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - ...
> - a type that contains a placeholder type.
>
> **[temp.arg.nontype]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#arg.nontype-1) If the type of a template-parameter contains a placeholder
>   type, the deduced parameter type is determined from the type of the
>   template-argument by placeholder type deduction. If a deduced
>   parameter type is not permitted for a template-parameter declaration
>   ([temp.param]), the program is ill-formed.

Now, `auto T::*` is a type the contains a placeholder type. And [placholder type deduction](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct) works just fine in a declaration of a variable in the form

```
auto Bar::* foo = &Bar::baz;
```

So VS v16.6.1 has no business rejecting such a non-type template parameter.